# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to return HTML from a method that handles the ajax request.

```
    public function loadDataAjax(Request $request)
{
    $output = '';
    $id = $request->id;

    $reviews = Review::where('tour_id','=',$id)
    ->where('status','=', 1)
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->limit(3)
    ->get();

    if(!$reviews->isEmpty())
    {
        foreach($reviews as $post)
        {
            $url = url('/');
            $body = substr(strip_tags($post->body),0,500);
            $body .= strlen(strip_tags($post->body))>500?"...":"";

                $output .= '<li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" class="comment byuser comment-author-physcode bypostauthor even thread-even depth-1" id="li-comment-62">
                <div id="comment-62" class="comment_container">
                    <img alt="" src="'.$url.'/'.Helper::catch_first_image($post->thumbnail).'" class="avatar avatar-60 photo" height="60" width="60">
                    <div class="comment-text">
                        <div class="star-rating" title="Rated '.$post->rating.' out of 5">
                        '.for ($i=1; $i <=5 ; $i++) { 
                            echo .'<i class="fa fa-star"></i>'.;
                        }.'
                        </div>
                        <p class="meta">
                            <span class="flag"><i class="flagstrap-icon flagstrap-'.strtolower($post->country).'"></i></span> <strong>'.ucfirst($post->fname). ucfirst($post->fname).'</strong><br> 
                            <time datetime="'.$post->created_at.'">'.date('M j, Y',strtotime($post->created_at)).'</time>
                            :
                        </p>
                        <strong>'.$post->title.'</strong>
                        <div class="description">
                            <p>'.$post->content.'</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>';                            
        }
        $output .= '<button class="btn-m btn btn-m-info" id="btn-more" data-id="'.$id.'" >Read More</button>';

        echo $output;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR)` error. Above is the complete code of my ajax-handling method. It was really long so I didn't write the whole code.

Comment: Share complete code, It seems missing php tag.

Comment: @Rishi Complete code added

Comment: I have given ans , replace your div with given div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope you are trying to print data from a Controller or a Model. I assume that you echo all the html. 
Please try the below code,

```
echo '<div class="comment-text">
    <div class="star-rating" title="Rated '.$post->rating.' out of 5">';
      for ($i=1; $i <=$post->rating ; $i++) { 
         echo '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
      }
echo '</div>';
```

If you are trying to echo html with some control structures in between, please echo the strings separately for code blocks above the control structure, within control structure & below control structure.

**Update:** this update is based on the update on your question,

```
 $output .= '<div class="comment-text">
    <div class="star-rating" title="Rated '.$post->rating.' out of 5">';
      for ($i=1; $i <=$post->rating ; $i++) { 
          $output .= '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
      }
 $output .= '</div>';
```

Comment: I just saw your update. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$output .= '<div class="comment-text">
    <div class="star-rating" title="Rated '.$post->rating.' out of 5">';
      for ($i=1; $i <=$post->rating ; $i++) { 
          $output .= '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
      }
 $output .= '</div>';
```